# Mysql variable in where clause

Tags: mysql

When i add last row "**and @summ > 0** (any condition)" 
It returns empty result. 
What i do wrong ? How right pass **@summ** into where clause ?

```
 select
      nore.nis as nore_curent,
      field_funds.value,
     (select @summ :=
        sum(field_amount.value - field_amount_tip.value)
          from
        nore
        inner join field_project on nore.nis = field_project.id
        inner join field_funds on field_funds.id = field_project.target_id
        inner join field_amount on nore.nid = field_data_field_amount.id
        inner join field_amount_tip on nore.nis = field_amount_tip.id
          where
        nore.`s` = 1
          and
        nore.`t` = 'p'
          and
        field_project.target_id = nore_curent) as amount
      from
       nore
      inner join field_funds on nore.nis = field_funds.id
       where
      nore.`s` = 1
       and
      nore.`t` = 'pp'
       and @summ > 0
```

Comment: Can't you use "and amount > 0"?

Comment: Try to use HAVING like this:
 where
      nore.`s` = 1
       and
      nore.`t` = 'pp'
HAVING amount > 0

Comment: Thanks :))) !!! working

Answer (score 0):

It's worthwhile to remaind some basics related to a conceptual (or a logical) order of evaluation of a Select statement- here:http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/sql/node22.html

The order is:

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. ORDER BY
6. SELECT

The WHERE clause is evaluated (executed) **before** the SELECT clause.
A value of `@summ` is calculated in SELECT clause (of the main query), so it's value is unknown when DMBS evaluates the WHERE clause.
Unknown = NULL
Therefore this query won't work as expected.
Rewrite the query into:

```
select
      nore.nis as nore_curent,
      field_funds.value,
     (select sum(field_amount.value - field_amount_tip.value)
          from
        nore
        inner join field_project on nore.nis = field_project.id
        inner join field_funds on field_funds.id = field_project.target_id
        inner join field_amount on nore.nid = field_data_field_amount.id
        inner join field_amount_tip on nore.nis = field_amount_tip.id
          where
        nore.`s` = 1
          and
        nore.`t` = 'p'
          and
        field_project.target_id = nore_curent) as amount
      from
       nore
      inner join field_funds on nore.nis = field_funds.id
       where
      nore.`s` = 1
       and
      nore.`t` = 'pp'
       and 0 < (select sum(field_amount.value - field_amount_tip.value)
                  from nore
                  inner join field_project on nore.nis = field_project.id
                  inner join field_funds on field_funds.id = field_project.target_id
                  inner join field_amount on nore.nid = field_data_field_amount.id
                  inner join field_amount_tip on nore.nis = field_amount_tip.id
                  where
                    nore.`s` = 1
                    and
                    nore.`t` = 'p'
                    and
                    field_project.target_id = nore_curent
)
```